# Make `pip install <package>` programatically install a different version of <package> depending on the other packages the user has installed?

Tags: pip, jupyter, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I'm a Python package developer looking to distribute my  to some users. Within these users, some of them are using JupyterLab 2.0, and some are using JupyterLab 3.0.

I'm wondering if it's possible if I can change some settings (or code in `setup.py`) so that, depending on what version of JupyterLab users have, a different version of my  is installed when the user runs `pip install <package>`.

For example:

1. User 1 has JupyterLab 2.0 installed. When they run `pip install <package>`, it installs package version `0.1.1`.
2. User 2 has JupyterLab 3.0 installed. When they run `pip install <package>`, it installs package version `0.2.1`.

Thanks for any information!

Comment: Off the top of my head: In your project version `0.1.1`: `install_requires = ['jupyterlab==2.0.*', ...]`; and in version `0.2.1`: `install_requires = ['jupyterlab==3.0.*', ...]`. Have not tested it, but it is the best I can think of right now. I guess the succes of this will depend on the dependency resolution algorithm.

Comment: @sinoroc, wouldn't that just fail installing for users with juputerlab-2.0 version?

Comment: This can probably be easier if user can just mention the version  and use install_requires just like what @sinroc suggested

Comment: It should not fail installing. If the dependency resolver is well coded, it should end up finding `0.1.1`, or any other version that is compatible with jupyterlab 2.

Answer (score 0):

In your setup.py, you can just use conditional statements to check the current version like below and set the correct installation version you want to install

```
import jupyterlab
version = jupyterlab.__version__

if version.startswith("2"):
    install_version="0.0.1"
elif version.startswith("3"):
    install_version="0.0.2"
```

Note: Don't forget to use exception handling to check if `jupyterlab` is at least installed

NOTE: This will not work if its used with pip. This will only work with source distribution and installed using `pip install setup.py`

Comment: That doesn't work with wheels, it only works with source distributions (sdist, .tar.gz). It's because `pip` doesn't run `setup.py` when *installing*, it only uses `setup.py` when *building* wheel on the developer's host.

Comment: @phd if I were to not use a wheel and rather work with a sdist, would this then work?

Comment: @NathanRush Yes.

Comment: @phd, i didn't realize that. Thanks.

Comment: Even with an sdist, this will only work once, then the wheel is cached and will ignore what version of `jupyterlab` is installed. One has to either clear pip's cache or use `--no-cache-dir` to force wheel rebuild.